# Find Matches using Regex in File Lines

Tags: c#

I am reading a list of files from a directory and looking for the patterns:

```
A. [[[Something]]] > Get the string "Something"

B. [[[Something///Comment]]] > Get the strings "Something" and "Comment"

C. [[[Enter between %0 and %1 characters|||Val 1|||Val 2]]] >> Get the string before the first ||| which is "Enter between %0 and %1 characters"
```

So I tried the following:

```
IList<String> files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.cshtml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

IDictionary<String, Tuple<Int32, String>> items = new Dictionary<String, Tuple<Int32, String>>();

Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[\[\[.*\]\]\]");

foreach (String file in files) {

  foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(file)) {

    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(line);

    foreach (Match match in matches) {

      if (match != null) {
        items.Add(match.Value, new Tuple<Int32, String>(number, file));
      }

    }

  }

}
```

**NOTE:** I am using ReadAllLines because I need to get the line number of each match I find.

Could I have some help in the following:

1. When using the Regex @"[[[.*]]]" I found a situation where is does not work:

   ViewInfo.Title("[[[Title]]]").Description("[[[Description]]]");

   I get Title]]]").Description("[[[Description]]]
2. I have not been able to apply the Rules (B) and (C).
3. Is it possible to improve performance or my code is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need an ungreedy expression: `.*?` will try to consume *as few characters as possible* .
2. Try this: `@"\[\[\[(?:(.*?)\|\|\|.*?|(.*?)///(.*?)|(.*?))\]\]\]"` (it is important to put the longest possible alternatives first or `.*?` could just eat up the whole string)
3. Use `File.ReadLines` along with a variable you'll increment at each iteration for counting lines. That way you won't have to hold the whole file in memory.

Comment: Only one problem: I get the [[[ and ]]] in the matches ... How can I remove them?

Comment: Don't use the whole match. Instead, use [match.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx). More Specifically `match.Groups[1]` and `match.Groups[2]` (for that last one, check its `Success` property).